# Facebook page tab changing

Tags: facebook-page

I want to change tab name of a facebook page.
Here is the code I am using

```
<?php
session_start();
$pageId=$_SESSION['pageid'];
require('sdk/facebook.php');
$appId = 'My App Id';
$secret = 'My App Secret';
$pageId = $pageId;
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $appId,
    'secret' => $secret,
));
$access_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
if($facebook->setAccessToken($access_token))
{
        $page_tabs=$facebook->api($pageId . '/tabs');
        $name=$page_tabs['data']['0']['name'];
        $tabid=$page_tabs['data']['0']['id'];
            if($name=="MyTab")
            {
                $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
                $facebook->api($tabid, 'POST', array(
        'custom_name' => 'MyTab New Name',
        'access_token'=>$_SESSION['token']
));
        }
            echo "OK";
}
?>
```

But I am getting error for Oauth Exception , it says you need to supply the accesstoken for this

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need few changes

**Instead of this**

```
'access_token'=>$_SESSION['token']
```

use this

```
//get the user access token 
        $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        echo "</br>" . 'User Access_Token:' . $atoken;
```